# The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain-policy

I'm writing a `chrome extension`, which inject an `iframe` to any webpage via `content script` like Evernote Web Clip. The source of `iframe` is from my extension. Something like this:

`chrome-extension://konnelaenlcciapjgocaolpdngjifmcb/layout/layout.html`

The problem is I can't get the document of iframe. I tried

`$(myiframe).contents().find('...')`
. The exception is thrown:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://stackoverflow.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "chrome-extension://konnelaenlcciapjgocaolpdngjifmcb".  The frame
>   requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed
>   has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.

I also tried:

```
myiframe.contentWindow.document.body.onload = function(){
    console.log(myiframe.contentWindow.document);
}
```

and the log is (no exception):

```
#document
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help!

Comment: Use postMessage or the extension message passing API to communicate between frames. The DOM is subject to the same origin policy regardless of what permissions your extension has.